# Why is this Framerate Independent When Adding An ImpulseForce Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I am facing an issue I want to push the object in the direction/Axis the player is moving towards I can do that using the getlastinputvector multiplying the force value but the thing is it is framerate dependent the output velocity is different when testing it in like 10FPS or 1000(uncapped)FPS how can i achieve the force not being affected by framerate and also the force being applied towards the player moving axis.

[image]

Comment: Divide by the current framerate?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of add impulse: https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Pawn/Components/CharacterMovement/AddImpulse/

"If you want to continually apply forces each frame, use AddForce()"

The add impulse is good for something like kicking a ball where it only happens once and the framerate would not matter.

The add force is better for something like having your character push an object as it is designed to be used every frame.

In your case it seems you should use add force.